# Case When Statement Between Two Identical Tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to compute a case when statement between two identical tables to generate an ouput, then filter that output with only its results. I keep getting the error that table cannot be found.

```
USE `options`;

SELECT * FROM `table` A, `tableb` B,

(SELECT * FROM `table` A, `tableb` B,

CASE 

WHEN hour(a.quote_datetime) = 9
 AND minute(a.quote_datetime) = 31 
 AND second(a.quote_datetime) = 0 
 AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.quote_datetime, a.expiration) > 0
 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.quote_datetime, a.expiration) < 7)
 AND ((ABS((SELECT b.strike FROM `tableb` WHERE 
     b.quote_datetime = (if( dayofweek(a.quote_datetime)=2, a.quote_datetime -'65:32:00' , a.quote_datetime - '17:32:00')) AND a.strike = b.strike AND a.option_type = b.option_type AND a.expiration = b.expiration) - (SELECT b.underlying_ask FROM `tableb` WHERE b.quote_datetime = (IF( dayofweek(a.quote_datetime)=2,  a.quote_datetime -'65:32:00', a.quote_datetime - '17:32:00')) AND a.strike = b.strike AND a.option_type = b.option_type AND a.expiration = b.expiration))) BETWEEN 0.25 AND 2.75)

 AND (((SELECT b.option_type FROM `tableb` WHERE b.quote_datetime = (if( dayofweek(a.quote_datetime)=2, a.quote_datetime -'65:32:00' , a.quote_datetime - '17:32:00')) AND a.strike = b.strike AND a.option_type = b.option_type AND a.expiration = b.expiration) = 'C' AND (SELECT B.strike FROM `tableb` WHERE b.quote_datetime = (if( dayofweek(a.quote_datetime)=2, a.quote_datetime -'65:32:00' , a.quote_datetime - '17:32:00')) AND a.strike = b.strike AND a.option_type = b.option_type AND a.expiration = b.expiration) > (SELECT B.underlying_ask FROM `tableb` WHERE b.quote_datetime = (if( dayofweek(a.quote_datetime)=2, a.quote_datetime -'65:32:00' , a.quote_datetime - '17:32:00')) AND a.strike = b.strike AND a.option_type = b.option_type AND a.expiration = b.expiration))

    OR (SELECT b.option_type FROM `tableb` WHERE b.quote_datetime = (if( dayofweek(a.quote_datetime)=2, a.quote_datetime -'65:32:00' , a.quote_datetime - '17:32:00')) AND a.strike = b.strike AND a.option_type = b.option_type AND a.expiration = b.expiration) = 'P' AND (SELECT B.strike FROM `tableb` WHERE b.quote_datetime = (if( dayofweek(a.quote_datetime)=2, a.quote_datetime -'65:32:00' , a.quote_datetime - '17:32:00')) AND a.strike = b.strike AND a.option_type = b.option_type AND a.expiration = b.expiration) < (SELECT B.underlying_ask FROM `tableb` WHERE b.quote_datetime = (if( dayofweek(a.quote_datetime)=2, a.quote_datetime -'65:32:00' , a.quote_datetime - '17:32:00')) AND a.strike = b.strike AND a.option_type = b.option_type AND a.expiration = b.expiration))

 THEN ((SELECT MAX(b.bid) FROM `tableb` WHERE date(b.quote_datetime) = date(a.quote_datetime) AND a.strike = b.strike AND a.option_type = b.option_type AND a.expiration = b.expiration) - (SELECT b.ask FROM `tableb` WHERE b.quote_datetime = (if( dayofweek(a.quote_datetime)=2, a.quote_datetime -'65:32:00' , a.quote_datetime - '17:32:00')) and a.strike = b.strike AND a.optiontype = b.optiontype AND a.expiration = b.expiration))/(SELECT b.ask FROM `tableb` WHERE b.quote_datetime = (if( dayofweek(a.quote_datetime)=2, a.quote_datetime -'65:32:00' , a.quote_datetime - '17:32:00')) AND b.strike = a.strike AND b.option_type = a.option_type AND a.expiration = b.expiration)

 ELSE NULL
 END) AS All_Filter
WHERE All_Filter IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You cannot use the result of `CASE` statement as a table like that. You'll have to move it to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks I'm still struggling with how I should approach it.